# Why doesn't the MSR605X respond to my bytes being sent from a C# WPF .NET application using HidSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, usb, hardware, hid

So I wanted to play around with the MSR605X lately and found it pretty hard to control ANY aspect of the hardware. I've created a sample code to try to turn off the LEDs on the device to no avail.

In this code (sample code, inspired by the code in my WPF application) I've created an infinite response read buffer, and also connects to the MSR by verifying if the product ID is 3 (MSR). I also verified that it's the MSR since it cannot be found when plugged out and also because the device description says "MSR" (magnetic stripe reader).

I've tried everything, including looking at the [documentation](https://usermanual.wiki/Pdf/MSR60520Programmers20Manual.325315846/view), a random MSR605X project in python ([here](https://github.com/oxplot/msrx/blob/master/msrx/__init__.py#L115)) and other various attempts at googling anything I can find. Still won't work.

Here's the sample code (no errors, just success but it doesn't actually work)

```cs
using HidSharp;

HidDevice[] GetHidDevices()
{
    var deviceList = DeviceList.Local;
    return deviceList.GetHidDevices().ToArray();
}

HidDevice[] devices = GetHidDevices();
HidDevice? device = null;
foreach (HidDevice iDevice in devices)
{
    if(iDevice.ProductID==3) device = iDevice; // Product ID 3 is a hacky method of verifying that its a MSR.
}
if (device == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No device");
    Environment.Exit(1);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Device found on path {device.DevicePath}.");
// Found device, connect
HidStream stream = device.Open();
stream.ReadTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
while (stream.CanWrite == false)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
Console.WriteLine("Opened stream.");
void writebytes(byte[] d)
{
    try
    {
        stream.Write(d,0,d.Length);
        stream.FlushAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes sent succesfully: " + d.Length); // No errors were ever displayed writing
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error sending bytes: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
writebytes(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x61 }); // Reset Command (Does not work)
writebytes(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x81 }); // Turn all LEDs off (Does not work)

// Read the response
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] response = new byte[64]; // adjust the buffer size as needed
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(response, 0, response.Length);
        stream.FlushAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine($"Response: {BitConverter.ToString(response, 0, bytesRead)}");
    }
}).Start();
```

Any help would do greatly, thanks.